# Vectorized funcion into a vectorized function Python

Tags: python, function, numpy, vectorization

I want to solve the next problem: I have a matrix of values, every value represents the rating of a movie, and I have the next function which returns a value (distance):

```
def getDistanceBetween2Movies(movie1, movie2):
    return np.linalg.norm(X[movie1]-X[movie2])
```

This function works fine, so then I wanted to get a list with all the distances from one specified movie to the others, and I did it like this, and it works

```
#Vector of indices of movies without our new user's one
moviesInd = np.arange(n_movies)
myMovie = 1

#Vectorizing our function
vfunc = np.vectorize(getDistanceBetween2Movies)
arrayDistances = vfunc(myMovie,moviesInd)
closestValue = np.min(arrayDistances)
closestIndex = np.argmin(arrayDistances)

print("Movie: " + str(closestIndex))
print("Distance: " + str(closestValue))
```

So the problem now is how to get a matrix with all the distances from every movie to the others, I'm trying to vectorize again this function in order to make the same operation n_movies times and gather it into a list or array.

```
    def getVectorDistances(i):
        vector = np.arange(n_movies)
        vFunc = np.vectorize(getDistanceBetween2Movies)
        return vFunc(i, vector)

    moviesInd = np.arange(n_movies)
    vFunc = np.vectorize(getVectorDistances)
    print(vFunc(moviesInd))

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-34-01b95a280035> in <module>()
          6 moviesInd = np.arange(n_movies)
          7 vFunc = np.vectorize(getVectorDistances)
    ----> 8 print(vFunc(moviesInd))
          9 
         10 

    c:\users\regis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       2737             vargs.extend([kwargs[_n] for _n in names])
       2738 
    -> 2739         return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
       2740 
       2741     def _get_ufunc_and_otypes(self, func, args):

    c:\users\regis\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py in _vectorize_call(self, func, args)
       2816 
       2817             if ufunc.nout == 1:
    -> 2818                 res = array(outputs, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=otypes[0])
       2819             else:
       2820                 res = tuple([array(x, copy=False, subok=True, dtype=t)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

This is what I did but it's not working and I'm stuck.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide example data for your movie ratings? Is it simply a 1D vector of float values (one element per movie)?

Comment: I have a 2D matrix called Y, every row represents one movie and every column one user, so Y[i,j] represents rating of movie i for user j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use the original `vfunc` without needing to nest it.  `vectorize` expects a function that accepts scalars.  It broadcasts the inputs as needed to pass scalar sets to the function.

It's that scalar input that's messing with the 2nd level of vectorizing.

But look at what we can do with the first vectorize:

```
In [389]: def getDistanceBetween2Movies(movie1, movie2):
     ...:     return np.linalg.norm(X[movie1]-X[movie2])
     ...: 
In [390]: X = np.arange(20)
```

Your function value with 2 scalars:

```
In [391]: getDistanceBetween2Movies(1,2)
Out[391]: 1.0
In [393]: getDistanceBetween2Movies(1,10)
Out[393]: 9.0

In [394]: vfunc = np.vectorize(getDistanceBetween2Movies)
```

`vectorize` with a scalar and array, effectively `[getDistanceBetween2Movies(i,j) for j in movielist]`:

```
In [395]: vfunc(1,np.arange(5))
Out[395]: array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
```

But I can give it two array, one a column vector.  This ends up doing an `outer` like evaluation:

```
In [396]: vfunc(np.arange(5)[:,None], np.arange(5))
Out[396]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 4.,  3.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Compare that output with the simple broadcasted difference between these two arrays:

```
In [397]: np.arange(5)[:,None]-np.arange(5)
Out[397]: 
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4],
       [ 1,  0, -1, -2, -3],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2],
       [ 3,  2,  1,  0, -1],
       [ 4,  3,  2,  1,  0]])
```

`vectorize` doesn't improve speed over direct iteration, but it can make evaluation of complicated scalar functions easier, especially if you are multiple inputs that need to be broadcasted against each other.

And as @Nils shows, you probably don't need to use `vectorize`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calculating the difference betwen matrix rows we are trying to vectorize the following double for loop

```
a = numpy.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
y = numpy.zeros(5, 5)
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        y[i, j] = numpy.linalg.norm(a[i, :] - a[j, :])
```

The first step is to vectorize the row difference

```
a[i, :] - a[j, :]  # difference between rows `i` and `j`
```

by calculating the "outer diffence" of your matrix rows, which yields a 3D tensor:

```
x = a[:, None, :] - a[None, :, :]
x.shape  # (5, 5, 5)
```

Afterwards, the difference of rows `i` and `j` can be found in the corresponding positions in the tensor:

```
x[i, j, :]  # difference between rows `i` and `j`
```

And the loop becomes

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a)):
        y[i, j] = numpy.linalg.norm(x[i, j, :])
```

However since we are now only iterating over the first two axes of `x` we can substitute the double loop with a vectorized call to `numpy.linalg.norm()`:

```
y = numpy.linalg.norm(x, axis=-1)
```

and get the distance of rows `i` and `j` again in the corresponding position

```
y[i, j]  # distance between rows `i` and `j`
```